# Unexpected framer-motion when key is equal to index vs when sat to random number

Tags: javascript, reactjs, framer-motion

Result when: `key={Math.floor(1+Math.random() * 10000)}` (no key clashes happens)
https://i.gyazo.com/c11af3485fd9cf7fe40cdacf003c2829.mp4

- Notice that all notifications receive the "intial + animate" whenever a new notification is added [unexpected behavior]

- The exit animation doesn't play [unexpected behavior]

Result when: `key={index}`
https://i.gyazo.com/4c733a692fa659b296ab91edbe71555c.mp4

- Notice only the newest notification get a "initial + animate" whenever a new notification is added [expected behavior]

- The exit animation doesn't play [unexpected behavior]

Questions:

1. Why is the behavior different? In both cases they all have unique keys (if not I will get an error in the console, which didn't happen, so I know this for sure)
2. Why is the exit animation not playing in either case? (I do have  an AnimatePresence)

---

full code:

```
const Notifications = (props) => {

    return (
            <AnimatePresence>
                <NotificationContext.Consumer>
                    {({notifications, removeNotifAt}) =>

                            <div id="notificationCenter">
                                {notifications.map((notif, index) =>

                                            <motion.div className={`notif ${notif.type.toLowerCase()}`} key={index} //key={Math.floor(1+Math.random() * 10000)}
                                                        onClick={() => removeNotifAt(index)}
                                                        initial={{ scale: 0.5 }}
                                                        animate={{ scale: 1 }}
                                                        exit={{ x: "-200px" }}
                                            >
                                                <div className="icon">
                                                    <img src={window.location.origin + '/times.svg'} alt=""/>
                                                </div>
                                                <div className="message">
                                                    <div className="title">{notif.title}</div>
                                                    {notif.msg} {index} ({1+Math.random() * 10000})
                                                </div>
                                            </motion.div>
                                )}
                            </div>

                    }
                </NotificationContext.Consumer>
            </AnimatePresence>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Why is the behavior different? In both cases, they all have unique keys (if not I will get an error in the console, which didn't happen, so I know this for sure)

They are both unique yes, but framer motion uses the key to track the component across rerenders. In the example you have for generating ids, the key is changing every rerender because your key generates function is evaluated right there in the render.

In the example where you generate the id you are ensuring that "React thinks this is a new component" every time, because you are changing the key every time.

There is less chatter from the index-based key because they are semi-consistent. However, this is not [best practice](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) because as notifications disappear their position in the array changes. Thus telling React: "Hey this is a new instance of this component."

2. Why is the exit animation not playing in either case?

Because framer-motion requires an explicit key on the immediate child beneath Animate Presence

**I Recommend**

1. Generate ids when within your notification create action so you can ensure the generation is only happening once
2. Move the `<NotificationContext.Consumer>` outside the `<AnimatePresnce>` so that you can add the explicit key right below it.

I put a bunch of work into a code sandbox for this problem because it comes up a bunch. Check it out to see a bunch of different cases and how they work: https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-using-context-with-animate-presensce-nuj0m

Comment: I think your repo is private. Can you add me to it joshuawootonn is my github. Or put the stuff in question on codesandbox

Comment: The problem now is most likely that you wrapped every element with an `AnimatePresence`. It should be inside the context consumption but outside the mapping of your elements.